# When running docker buildx bake, is it possible to set build args like BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

We're using docker buildx bake with a build definition file to build a set of images. We need to set BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE which would normally be set with --build-args if running docker buildx build.

How can this arg be set with bake?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the answer is: its not necessary. The env var is just a [hint](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/606#issuecomment-1149130479).